# How to limit rule to a subset of cpp toolchains?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have a rule like this

```py
do_action = rule (
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {
        ...
        "_cc_toolchain": attr.label(default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:current_cc_toolchain")),
    },
    fragments = ["cpp"],
    toolchains = [
        "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type",
        ],
)
```

I define custom cc_toolchain for a custom cpu:

```py
toolchain(
    name = "cc-toolchain-%{toolchain_name}",
    toolchain = ":cc-compiler-%{toolchain_name}",
    # can be run on this platform
    target_compatible_with = [
        "@platforms//os:windows",
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64",
    ],
    toolchain_type = "@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain_type",
)

cc_toolchain_suite(
    name = "toolchain",
    toolchains = {
        "%{cpu}": ":cc-compiler-%{toolchain_name}",
    },
)
```

I use `--crostool_top` to select this toolchain when needed.

I want to allow my custom rule to be invoked only if --crostool_top matches one of my custom toolchains. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new [`constraint_setting`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/platform.html#constraint_setting) with a [`constraint_value`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/platform.html#constraint_value) which only your toolchains are `target_compatible_with`, and then make all targets which use your rules `target_compatible_with` it.

Something like this in a BUILD file:

```py
constraint_setting(name = "is_my_toolchain")

constraint_value(
  name = "yes_my_toolchain",
  constraint_setting = ":is_my_toolchain",
)
```

And then add `yes_my_toolchain` to `target_compatible_with` on all your toolchains.

Easiest way to force using it with every usage of your rule is with a [macro](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html). Rename the actual rule to `_do_action` (so it's private and can't be loaded directly from any `BUILD` file) and add:

```py
def do_action(target_compatible_with = [], **kwargs):
  _do_action(
    target_compatible_with = target_compatible_with + [
      "//your_package:yes_my_toolchain",
    ],
    **kwargs
  )
```

Comment: What if a rule is stored in do_action.bzl and then loaded in dependent project? I can't define this constraint directly in do_action.bzl, or BUILD file in dependent project.

Comment: Use a BUILD file in your project. The one for the package containing do_action.bzl probably makes the most sense. You can reference it like `@my_workspace_name//my_package:yes_my_toolchain` as an absolute reference.

Comment: I think make a prviate attribute of do_action rule is better than a private rule.